# userRole loads white page after first test unless preserverURL: true is used, preventing navigating directly to a page with .page

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When setting up a test the .page method won't visit a page or the page will be white because of a failure with the authentication process with userRole. The only fix so far has been to add `preserveURL: true` the issue with this is the tests are taking a substantially longer time as the test must then navigate to the proper page.

Every post and docs I've read say this should just work, I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction or offer some things I can try.

Adding it all in one file, but each is split into their own file.

```
// authentication file .js
import { Role } from "testcafe";

const userLogins = require('../logins.json');
let users = [];
let passwords = [];

userLogins.forEach( data => {
    users.push(data.name);
    passwords.push(data.password);
})

const admin = Role('https://foo.example.com/', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#email', users[0], { paste: true, replace: true })
        .typeText('#password', passwords[0], { paste: true, replace: true })
        .click('#login-btn');
}); // adding the option { preserveURL: True } here will cause all tests to pass successfully if I add code to each test to nav to the correct page
    // and disable .page in the test spec

export { admin };

// page model file .js
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";

class FooPage {
    constructor() {
        this.searchInput = Selector('#searchInput');
        this.orderCount = Selector('#orderNumber');
        this.businessName = Selector('#businessName');
        this.contactNumber = Selector('#contactNumber');
    };

    async searchResults(selector, searchText) {
        // enter search term
        await t
            .typeText(this.searchInput, searchText, {paste: true, replace: true})
            .pressKey('enter');

        // check how many rows were returned
        const rowCount = await this.orderCount.count;
        let searchResults = []

        // verify all rows returned contain only our search text
        for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            let text = await selector.nth(i).innerText;
            searchResults.push(text);
            await t.expect(searchResults[i]).contains(searchText);
    }
}

export default FooPage;

// test spec file .js
import { admin } from "../authentication";
import FooPage from "../FooPage";

const fooPage = new FooPage();

fixture `Test searching foo orders`
    .page`https://foo.example.com/#/foo_orders` // this works for first test then loads white page thereafter
    .beforeEach( async t => {
        await t
            .resizeWindow(1284, 722)
            .useRole(admin)
    });

// this test will work correctly
test(`User can search via order number`, async t => {
    await fooPage.searchResults(fooPage.orderCount, 'FOO111');
});

// this test will load a white page and fail
test(`User can search via business purchaser`, async t => {
    await fooPage.searchResults(fooPage.businessName, 'Foo Company');
});

// this test will load a white page and fail
test(`User can search via phone number`, async t => {
    await fooPage.searchResults(fooPage.contactNumber, '555-555-5555');
});
```

I won't be able to post an example site as it's all proprietary. This will work though if I remove the .page and add in `preserveUrl: true` into the authentication file. The spec, page model and authentication file all clearly work.

But, I can't use .page to navigate directly to the page I want. This is increasing test times and breaking the cardinal rule of navigating directly to the page to test.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. It looks like your app has some specifics, which do not allow it to work correctly without the `preserveUrl` option.
However, it's difficult to determine the cause of the issue without a working example. Since you can't share an example here, I would ask you to send it to the official TestCafe support email: support@devexpress.com

Please note that the DevExpress TestCafe policy prevents us (TestCafe Team) from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If we need to access non-public parts of your website or pass through authorization pages, please ask the website owner to send us (support@devexpress.com) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately we won't be able to give consent to access the site.